# jquery ajax with querySelector.value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to coding, so my question is hopefully easy to answer.

I want to send an ajax request with data from two radio buttons.

This is the function

```
pOk = function () {
var p1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "Player1"]:checked').value;
var p2 = document.querySelector('input[name = "Player2"]:checked').value;
$.ajax({method: 'POST', url: '/new_game', data: {p1: p1, p2: p2 }});
}
```

However the data is not working.

```
document.writeln("This is p1 "+p1);
```

works, so does

```
$.ajax({method: 'POST', url: '/new_game', data: {p1: "Player1", p2: "Player2" }});
```

### html:

```
<fieldset> 
<input type="radio" id="p11" name="Player1" value="Player1">
<label for="p11"> Player1</label><br> 
<input type="radio" id="p12" name="Player1" value="Player2">
<label for="p12"> Player2</label><br> 
<input type="radio" id="p13" name="Player1" value="Player3">
<label for="p13"> Player3</label> 
</fieldset> 
.... another fieldset ... 
<button id="playerok">OK</button>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please put this into a *complete* example.  In what order is this running? Any - any reason you're using `document.querySelector` instead of simply `$('input[name="Player1"').is(':checked')`?

Comment: I edited the code above.

Comment: Great.  This is helpful.  Define `the data is not working`.  What you have should work properly, *assuming* the checkboxes are checked.  How are you checking the `data` on the other end of the request? What IS being output?

Comment: Please edit question and add your HTML, including the button used to launch the ajax code.

Comment: I'd like to call this block
` post '/new_game' do
    @match = Match.new(params[:p1], params[:p2])
end`

This works when I pass the player names as a string directly, as I wrote before. The data is then read and stored as well as shown in the web-app.

Comment: Here is the HTML
`<fieldset>
<input type="radio" id="p11" name="Player1" value="Player1"><label for="p11"> Player1</label><br> 
 <input type="radio" id="p12" name="Player1" value="Player2"><label for="p12"> Player2</label><br> 
 <input type="radio" id="p13" name="Player1" value="Player3"><label for="p13"> Player3</label>
 </fieldset>
 .... another fieldset ...
 <button id="playerok">OK</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note - Your `$.ajax` code syntax is incorrect. It should be `type:"post"` not `method:"post"`

Perhaps something like this:

```
$('#playerok').click(function(){
    var p1 = $('input[name = "Player1"]:checked').val();
    var p2 = $('input[name = "Player2"]:checked').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: '/new_game',
        data: {p1: p1, p2: p2 },
        success: function(d){
            if (d.length) alert(d);
        }
    });
});
```

Note: I am not familiar with your method of specifying the AJAX file. I have always used something like:

```
url: 'new_game.php',
```

In your `new_game` file, as a test, change it so that all it does is echo back a test result. You have not specified your back-end language, but in PHP I would do something like this:

**new_game.php:**

```
<?php
    echo 'Got to here';
```

Then, I ensure the alert fires in the AJAX `success:` function:

```
if (d.length) alert(d);
```

Once that works, make the `new_game` file send back the data you sent to it -- again as a test, to see what it is receiving.

Then, finish your app.